Landscape scriptexection.py: No such file or directory: '/tmp/tmpsh_6rdsp'
I try to execute a script from on-premise Landscape on a client machine. Something simple like echo "Hello World". I receive the response FAILED with the following details:
Upon execvpe /tmp/tmpsh_6rdsp ('/tmp/tmpsh_6rdsp',) in environment id 139639884798464 :  
Traceback (most recent call last):     
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/internet/process.py", line 397, in _fork self._execChild(path, uid, gid, executable, args, environment)   
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/internet/process.py", line 468, in _execChild os.execvpe(executable, args, environment)   
    File "/usr/lib/python3.10/os.py", line 584, in execvpe _execvpe(file, args, env)   
    File "/usr/lib/python3.10/os.py", line 598, in _execvpe exec_func(file, *argrest)  
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/tmpsh_6rdsp'  

When I connect the client to a Landscape hosted by Ubuntu, the remote execution of the script is working, so my assumption is the Landscape server is the problem not the Landscape client, but I couldn't find errors in the Landscape server logs that would help me troubleshooting.
The only hint I get is a error message "Unable to reach secrets client". I couldn't find out what actually this means.
When I combine my half-knowledge with this topic here ...
Change tmp-directory used by Landscape?
I would assume, either landscape server cannot create the script files in /tmp or cannot transfer the scripts to the client machine.
